# Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: php

I have written a module to display images on my site, but I'm getting the following error on the site:

```
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in /public_html/camps/modules/mod_slider/mod_slider.php on line 24
```

This is what is showing on line 24:

```
<?php if (!empty($params->get('image-1')) || !empty($params->get('image-1-alt')) || !empty($params->get('image-1-caption'))) { ?>
```

Any ideas what's gone wrong?

The server is running PHP version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to **PHP 5.5**, the function `empty()` can only be used on variables, not return values, so you have to approach it like this:

```
$image = $params->get('image-1');
$alt = $params->get('image-1-alt');
$caption = $params->get('image-1-caption');
if (!empty($image) || !empty($alt) || !empty($caption)) {
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Good answer. +1 but no flowers

Comment: lol...bought a Poinsettia yesterday for my wife, but WAS thinking of you, lol.  And nice to know about PHP5.5 (still on 5.4 AND 5.2 here)

Answer (score 4):

Just a little addition to @GDP's answer.

Instead of checking whether the variables are empty or not, you could set default values for them like so:

```
$image   = $params->get('image-1', 'images/image.png');
$alt     = $params->get('image-1-alt', 'Generic Alt');
$caption = $params->get('image-1-caption', 'Generic Caption');
```

Then simply create a generic image that will show is nothing has been set.